# Proper way to chain require

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new to node and npm so thanks for bearing with me here.

I want to package/modularize a series of classes(in separate files) that inherit from a base class and all classes should be visible to the end user/programmer. In other words I want to preserve the previous requires so that I have a master object the end user can require to get everything. require('Event') also requires Item for the user/programmer.

```
"use strict";
const Item = require('./Item');

module.exports = class Event extends Item {
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.TypeName = 'Event';
        this.JSON = '{}';
    }

    static Bind(service, eventId) {
        return new Event();
    }
}
```

and

```
"use strict";

module.exports =  class Item {
    constructor() {
        this.TypeName = 'Item';
        this.JSON = '{}';
    }

    static Bind(service, itemId) {
        return new Item();      
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your question? Does the layout you've described in your code example not work? When a module is required, its contents, including any `require`s that it makes, are evaluated, so you don't need to do anything special here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to export multiple things from a a module, then you export a parent object and each of the things you want to export is a property on that object.  This is not "chaining" as there really isn't such a thing for exporting multiple top level items from a module.

```
module.exports = {
    Event, Item
};

class Item {
    constructor() {
        this.TypeName = 'Item';
        this.JSON = '{}';
    }

    static Bind(service, itemId) {
        return new Item();      
    }
}
class Event extends Item {
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.TypeName = 'Event';
        this.JSON = '{}';
    }

    static Bind(service, eventId) {
        return new Event();
    }
}
```

Then, someone using this module would do:

```
const m = require('myModule');
let item1 = new m.Item();
let event1 = new m.Event();
```

Or, you can assign them to top level variables within the module:

```
const {Item, Event} = require('myModule');
let item1 = new Item();
let event1 = new Event();
```

---

If you have multiple classes each in their own file and you want to be able to load them all with one `require()` statement, then you can create a master file that does a `require()` on each of the individual files and combines them into one exported object.  Then, when you want to import all of them, you can just require in the master file.

node.js modules are designed such that you `require()` in everything you need in that module and you do that in each module that wants to use something.  This enhances reusability or shareability of modules because each module independently imports the things it needs.  You don't have all this global state that has to be imported somewhere before any of the other modules work.  Instead, each module is self-describing.  It also makes it much more obvious to people working on a module what it depends on because there's a `require()` statement for everything it depends upon.  This may seem like a bit of extra typing for people coming from different environments where you might just import something once into a global namespace (and it is more typing), but there are very good reasons it is done this way and honestly, it doesn't take long to get used to it and then you can enjoy some of the benefits to doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is similar to what I wanted, is there a way to do this when the classes are separated into separate file though? Similarly, I don't want to have to require the same objects over and over when I use them in another internal file

Comment: @DavidBell - Create one master file that requires in the other files and combines them into one exported object and then all you have to do is to require in the one master file.  In node.js module development, you requrie in everything a given module needs in that module.  That's how node.js modules work and it is done this way for good modularity reaons.  You don't just require them in one place in your app and them use them in all your other files. Keep in mind that you don't have to create a separate file for every single class. Files in node.js dev are more commonly shareable module units.

Comment: I suspect you are right. Importing explicitly what you need seems like a pain if you have to import the same thing many times across certain files but the benefits are obvious. Checked as answer, thanks!